# Fastest way to search string for substring using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I am using DataTables plugin for jQuery. Within the DataTable I have approximately 16 tr rows with 4 td columns each. The DataTables plugin provides an API extension that allows searching for a string in all cells of the table or in all cells of a specified column.

The search extension returns an array of row indices where a match was found. For example, [3, 7, 10, 11]. The search extension originally supported an exact match search which I had to modify from:

```
if (val == sSearch)
```

to:

```
if (val.indexOf(sSearch) > 0)
```

My customization is certainly the cause of the performance issues I'm having, but it was necessary since the contents of the cells are updated dynamically and therefore unpredictable for performing an exact match search.

An example haystack:

```
<input id="_HeatOfRejection" class="form-control text-right text-box single-line" type="text" name="HeatOfRejection" measureid="HeatLoad" value="5000.0" uomid="MBH">
```

An example needle:

```
' measureid=\"HeatLoad\" '
```

The average time required to perform a search for needle is ~17.5ms and since the inner loop contains ~16 different needles with an outer loop causing additional loops of the inner loop, the processing time is too noticeable. It's not horrible, but can take 2-3 seconds. On that note, this is not a critical function.

What I am wanting to know is if there is a faster way than using indexOf() to perform this search. Using a jQuery selector might be faster, but the id is unknown/unimportant to the search. Multiple controls can contain the needle and so I have to search the entire column.

Comment: Is search for element `attribute` match `$("[measureid=HeatLoad]")`?

Comment: as far as i know indexOf is a native implementation by the browser's javascript engine, javascript functions can't be faster than that. Most likely the performance issues are caused by other parts of your script, which we don't have much visibility. It would be better if you can include a simple http://jsfiddle.net/ which display your problem, so that others can fiddle around and try to help you

Answer (score 0):

To search for an element having an attribute with a specific value, you can use

```
$("[measureid='HeatLoad']");
```

It will return all the elements having attribute 'measureid' with value 'HeatLoad'.

Comment: @M J, I understand why you provided this solution. I need the indices of the table rows that contains the matching measureid. There is more than one row with a matching measureid. Using a selector would definitely speed things up and I've consider how it might be done that way. I just thought I might be able to live with the way it is and wondered if there might be a quicker function that indexOf().

Comment: @rwkii : Yup using this selector you can have the all the elements satisfying the selection condition but if you need indices then this will not work.